# Change tab using onClickItem in ListActivity

Tags: android

Can someone please tell me how to change tab by clicking on element INSIDE the tab? I already tried it with global data. The code looks like this:

```
public class Tabs extends TabActivity {

int tabNumber = 0;
private TabHost tabHost;
int returnedTabNumber = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tribocracy.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("map").setIndicator("Map",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Areas.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("areas").setIndicator("Areas",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_albums))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Settings.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("settings").setIndicator("Settings",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_albums))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(tabNumber);


}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


            GlobalData globalData = ((GlobalData)getApplicationContext());
            returnedTabNumber = globalData.getTabNumber();
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(returnedTabNumber);   


}
```

}

The global adapter looks like this:

```
public class GlobalData extends Application {
//----------------------------------------------------
      private int Point1;   //define the vars here
      private int Point2;   //define the vars here
      private int Point3;   //define the vars here
      private int Point4;   //define the vars here
      private int Point5;   //define the vars here
      private int Point6;   //define the vars here
      private int tabNumber;

      public int getTabNumber() //getter of the value
      {     
        return tabNumber;
      }

      public int setTabNumber(int number)     //setter of the value
      {
        tabNumber = number;
        return tabNumber;
      }
```

}

Now when I'm trying to change tab in my ListActivity tab by clicking on one of the items it doesn't do anything and stays on the ListActivity tab. Perhaps I shouldn't use onResume() here. Basically I want to go to first tab when I click on one of the items in the list. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use Intents. And there are many ways to use Intents for this. This works especially well for some cases, for example where the activity is displaying some content from a content provider. I'll describe one possible method below:

1. For the Activity that hosts the tabs, give it an intent filter if it doesn't already have one. For example, if it's an 'item detail'-style Activity, maybe its intent filter can match for `ACTION_VIEW` on a certain content type like `vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.somecontent`.
2. Have the Activity take an extra such as `focus_tab`, and in the Activity's `onCreate`, after setting up the tabs, set the active tab to the one specified by this `focus_tab` extra.
3. Override `onNewIntent`, and in that method, look for that same `focus_tab` extra and set the active to the one specified by that extra.
4. Now, in your button code (i.e. a button inside one of your tab content activities), create an Intent that will start your host Activity, and give it a `focus_tab` extra corresponding to the tab you want to switch to. Add the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` Intent flag so you don't create a new instance of the host Activity. And then, call `startActivity` on that Intent you just created.

*Note*: I haven't tried this myself, but it should work in theory.